# subversion tagging failed via "svn-tag" plugin

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

svn-tag plugin throws this error. Please advise:

```
Subversion copy failed. svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT /svn/project1/!svn/ver/4435/Tags failed
Build step 'Perform Subversion tagging on successful build' marked build as failure

 Jenkins :1.549v
 Subversion Tagging: 2.0v
```

Comment: Can you find out what if any error you're receiving in the server error log?  The error you've given is a generic error for any request from a DAV server failing, which unfortunately is not going to help much in understanding why this is failing.

Comment: Can you attach jenkins log?

Comment: Have you found any solution?